# YouTube Data API V3: Fetch multiple videoCategoryId videos

Tags: youtube-api

I am using **YouTube Data API Version 3.0** in one of my projects to fetch my channel video details from YouTube. I don't want the user to login to his/her Google account that's why I am directly using Search.list method instead of going through the OAuth 2.0 way.

Usually I fetch data using following URL.

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={API_KEY}&maxResults=5&part=snippet&type=video&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}

Now, **I want to fetch data of 5 different categories at a time**. What I can do is, hit the same URL 5 times with query string as

key={API_KEY}&maxResults=1&part=snippet&type=video&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&videoCategoryId={CATEGORY_ID}

or,

**Is there a way like**

key={API_KEY}&maxResults=5&part=snippet&type=video&channelId={CHANNEL_ID}&videoCategoryId={**CATEGORY_ID_1, CATEGORY_ID_2, CATEGORY_ID_3, CATEGORY_ID_4, CATEGORY_ID_5**}

**I want to fetch only 1 video data per category**. That is why I have given 5 comma separated category IDs.

Also, Search.list method does not give videoCategoryId. To get it, I have to use

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id={VIDEO_ID}&key={API_KEY}

**Is there any way to get videoCategoryId in Search.list method?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You need to have 5 queries for that. Even if you were able to give 5 category ids, it wouldn't understand to pick up one video data for each one.
2. Search doesn't return videoCategory right now, videos->list has it.
3. There is no problem going through OAuth2, you can just ask read-only permission, and should be fine. Users can pick their already stored accounts easily.

Comment: Thanx for your quick reply. Regard' OAuth2, first I'll try to implement with read-only permissions. If anything goes wrong, I'll ask here...